# Centos 6.5 make caffe error

Tags: caffe

all. when I make caffe on centos 6.5, I faced error like this:

```
$ make all
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
........
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
CXX tools/finetune_net.cpp
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/finetune_net.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_sdot_sub'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_dgemv'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_dgemm'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_sgemm'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_scopy'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_dasum_sub'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_sgemv'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_sasum_sub'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_sscal'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_daxpy'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_saxpy'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_dscal'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_ddot_sub'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `F77_dcopy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/finetune_net.bin] Error 1
```

I think it's atlas config error. but I don't know how to config it. the caffe document just say uncomment BLAS_LIB := /usr/lib64/atlas/, and I do that. but also get this error.
Anybody know why?  thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

It is linking error. Apply following command in your console and then clean and make again:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your_blas_so_path
```

Comment: use ldd command to see the caffe.so file is still missing some library....

Comment: it's only `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff344fc000) ` cannot find lib file. atlas lib file could find. `libatlas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.so.3 (0x00007fbe9362d000)`

Comment: see the dependencies of `/usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.so.3` may be it requires some libraries which is not installed in your system

Comment: All dependencies of `/usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.so.3` can be find.

Comment: do you have `lapack`  & `cblas` development version installed?

Comment: Package lapack-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package blas-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: add those installed paths export using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path1:/path2:/path3`  and remake from that console

Comment: I find lapack on `/usr/lib64`, and cblas, atlas on `/usr/lib64/atlas`.so I `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/lib64/atlas`, but get same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125972/discussion-between-md-nazmul-kibria-and-aaronshan).